# How to show a display:none DIV using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a DIV which has a display set to none, by using javascript I tried showing it by using the onclick of a button. But what happens is the exact opposite. My DIV is already shown and when I click the button it hides the DIV. What am i doing wrong here, please HELP!

This is my button and the div:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">SHOW</button>
    <div id="how_to_form">
      <img src="../images/view.png">
    </div>
```

This is the JS code:

```
function myFunction() {
     var x = document.getElementById("how_to_form").style.display = 'none';
     if (x.style.display === "none") {
      x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      x.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
```

Comment: You are assigning `x` to the result of `= 'none'`. At that point, `x` is the string `'none'` and has no `style` property

Comment: Yes I assigned it using .style.display. Is that the wrong way of assigning its display settings?

Comment: Change variable x value to var x= document.getElementById("how_to_form")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line there has a *double* assignment:

```
var x = document.getElementById("how_to_form").style.display = 'none';
```

It first assigns the `display` to none:

```
document.getElementById("how_to_form").style.display = 'none';
```

and then takes the result of that expression (which is the string you assigned), and assigns it to `x`:

```
var x = 'none';
```

Which isn't what you want. First declare the variable for the element, then assign its style.

Also, it sounds like you want the element to start out hidden - assign its initial style *outside* the function:

```
const form = document.getElementById("how_to_form");
form.style.display = 'none';
function myFunction() {
  if (form.style.display === "none") {
    form.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    form.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Or, to be more concise, use the conditional operator:

```
function myFunction() {
  form.style.display = form.style.display === "none"
  ? 'block'
  : 'none';
}
```

Also consider attaching the handler properly using Javascript, rather than using inline HTML attributes, which are generally considered to be pretty poor practice and can be hard to manage:

```
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', myFunction);
```

Comment: About this handler property, Is that an alternate way in creating a button?

Comment: That's the alternate (better) way to *attach the handler*, rather than using an inline HTML attribute.

Comment: But wouldn't it be harder to style the button? If I am styling it using CSS?

Comment: Not at all - all you have to do is remove the `onclick="myFunction()"` and use the line `document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', myFunction);` instead, you don't need to make any other changes.

Comment: Did you mean like this? 
    `<button type="submit" document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', myFunction());`

Comment: No, just remove the `onclick` attribute from the button in the HTML. The Javascript should still be in your Javascript file, don't try to put Javascript in HTML

Comment: I'm in confusion, If I am to put this handler, in which part? After the function?

Comment: Wherever you want - function declarations are hoisted, after all, so whether it's before or after shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

have you checked if you have already set a default style to your div?
you either have to set your div's default style to display:none by inline

```
<div id="how_to_form" style="display:none">
```

or by css

```
<style>
    #how_to_form{ display:none }
</style>
```

Comment: Oh thanks @pokken! This works! Did not thought css would do the thing. But can I ask what is wrong with my display = 'none' in my javascript code?

Answer (score 1):

Issue is your variable assignment

Chaining the assignment operator is possible in order to assign a single value to multiple variables.

Please refer this link for variable assignment options
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators

var x = y= 10

Then both x and y values are 10

Similarly in your code var x is none

To achieve expected result , use below option
1. set CSS for html_to_form to display:none
2.In your code change variable x assignment to 
var x = document.getElementById("html_to_form")